# Вопросы внутри

Tags: языкознание

Приятно иметь дело с образованными интеллегентными людьми. Вопросы:
1.Правильно ли пишу "микрозадержками"?
2.Правильно ли поставлены тире и запятые в предложении: "Только в этих практиках начинают работать верхние Цихаи – Интан – он же «третий глаз», универсальная энергия и макушка – она же «Небесная Энергия». "

Answer (score 6):

Микрозадержками  - правильно, слитно. Первое тире оценить не могу, так как смысла не понимаю. А перед пояснением (он же третий глаз, она же "Небесная Энергия") лучше поставить запятые, а не тире.

Comment: Спасибо. А такой вопрос: слово "цигун" можно склонять или только "цигун", как слово "пальто"?

Answer (score 1):

Склоняется

```
циг'ун, -а
```

Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.